# pgsql function cannot execute

Tags: plpgsql, sql-injection, dynamic-sql, pgadmin

I tried to execute this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.increases_chrono(
    chrono_seq_name text,
    chrono_id_name text)
    RETURNS TABLE(chrono_id bigint) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $$
DECLARE
    retval bigint;
BEGIN
    -- Check if sequence exist, if not create
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM pg_class where relname = chrono_seq_name ) THEN
      EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || chrono_seq_name || '" INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1;';
    END IF;
    -- Check if chrono exist in parameters table, if not create
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM parameters where id = chrono_id_name ) THEN
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO parameters (id, param_value_int) VALUES ( ''' || chrono_id_name || ''', 1)';
    END IF;
    -- Get next value of sequence, update the value in parameters table before returning the value
    SELECT nextval(chrono_seq_name) INTO retval;
      UPDATE parameters set param_value_int = retval WHERE id =  chrono_id_name;
      RETURN QUERY SELECT retval;
END;
$$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.increases_chrono(text, text)
    OWNER TO maarch;
```

but when i call him like this command:

```
SELECT increases_chrono('chrono_DAP_2023_seq' ,'chrono_DAP_2023')
```

> i have error : ERROR:  relation "chrono_dap_2023_seq" does not exist
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT nextval(chrono_seq_name)"
> PL/pgSQL function increase_chrono(text,text) line 14 at SQL statement

SQL state: 42P01
someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in case sensitivity. The `CREATE` looks like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "chrono_DAP_2023_seq" 
   INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1;
```

The identifier is inside double quotes - so it is case sensitive.

But when you try to use it, then the variable `chrono_seq_name` is not passed inside double quotes, so it is not case sensitive identifier. Using `quote_ident` function fix it:

```
-- Get next value of sequence, update the value in parameters 
---table before returning the value
SELECT nextval(quote_ident(chrono_seq_name)) INTO retval;
```

The building string like `EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || chrono_seq_name || '" INC ...` is wrong. Don't do it ever. It is SQL injection vulnerable. You should to use function `quote_ident` again, or function `format` with placeholder `%I`:

```
EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I', chrono_seq_name);
```

There is another issue. There is not any reason, and it is contra-productive to return a table. The call of table functions is more expensive. This function should to return just bigint:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.increases_chrono(
    chrono_seq_name text,
    chrono_id_name text)
    RETURNS bigint 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $$
BEGIN
  ...
  RETURN retval;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: thanks...now the problem is the instruction IF NOT EXIST to verify if sequence are created or not

Comment: @Jules78 - No, there should not be any problem - the column relname doesn't contains double quotes there, and string compare in pg is case sensitive.